# Why does the arrow in that slider doesnt work?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a Slider for my Website and one of the arrows is completely cracked. I have no idea why.
See here:

[image: Why???]

I have no idea what to do because i dont even know where to search for that problem. Is it a CSS or JS problem?

Here is the JS, HTML and CSS Code:

HTML:

```
<li class="l-section section">
              <div class="work">
                <h2>Contact me</h2>
                <div class="work--lockup">
                  <ul class="slider">
                    <li class="slider--item slider--item-left">
                      <a href="mailto:mail">
                        <div class="slider--item-image">
                          <img src="assets/img/work-victory.jpg" alt="E-Mail">
                        </div>
                        <p class="slider--item-title">E-Mail</p>
                        <p class="slider--item-description">Send me an E-Mail and I would love to help you.</p>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="slider--item slider--item-center">
                      <a href="#0">
                        <div class="slider--item-image">
                          <img src="assets/img/work-metiew-smith.jpg" alt="Fiverr">
                        </div>
                        <p class="slider--item-title">Fiverr</p>
                        <p class="slider--item-description">Book me directly on Fiverr and get you Website done in a few days.</p>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="slider--item slider--item-right">
                      <a href="#0">
                        <div class="slider--item-image">
                          <img src="assets/img/work-alex-nowak.jpg" alt="Shop">
                        </div>
                        <p class="slider--item-title">Shop</p>
                        <p class="slider--item-description">Check out my premium Templates and exclusive services.</p>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                  <div class="slider--prev">
                    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
                      viewBox="0 0 150 118" style="enable-background:new 0 0 150 118;" xml:space="preserve">
                    <g transform="translate(0.000000,118.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)">
                      <path d="M561,1169C525,1155,10,640,3,612c-3-13,1-36,8-52c8-15,134-145,281-289C527,41,562,10,590,10c22,0,41,9,61,29
                        c55,55,49,64-163,278L296,510h575c564,0,576,0,597,20c46,43,37,109-18,137c-19,10-159,13-590,13l-565,1l182,180
                        c101,99,187,188,193,199c16,30,12,57-12,84C631,1174,595,1183,561,1169z"/>
                    </g>
                    </svg>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slider--next">
                    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 150 118" style="enable-background:new 0 0 150 118;" xml:space="preserve">
                    <g transform="translate(0.000000,118.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)">
                      <path d="M870,1167c-34-17-55-57-46-90c3-15,81-100,194-211l187-185l-565-1c-8BQAzQwVETtFWGmAFZjAwNSYA7M4EczfocpPa2kZ6AiC1tVQuAhJTRjLG5Nkk4QqFWHxiKBdi6RuUFjC5zMhvhUyK7tatMA-20,39-29,61-29c28,0,63,30,298,262c147,144,272,271,279,282c30,51,23,60-219,304C947,1180,926,1196,870,1167z"/>
                    </g>
                    </svg>                    
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
```

CSS:

```
.work {
    position: relative;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    width: 960px;
    max-width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 0 auto
}

@media (max-width: 1180px) {
    .work {
        max-width: 100%
    }
}

.work h2 {
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center
}

.work--lockup {
    position: relative
}

.work--lockup .slider {
    position: relative;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none
}

.work--lockup .slider--item {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    text-align: center
}

.work--lockup .slider--item a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #858585
}

.work--lockup .slider--item-title {
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase
}

.work--lockup .slider--item-description {
    display: none;
    max-width: 250px;
    margin: 0 auto
}

.work--lockup .slider--item-image {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden
}

.work--lockup .slider--item-image img {
    width: 100%
}

.work--lockup .slider--item-left {
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    display: block
}

.work--lockup .slider--item-right {
    top: 50%;
    right: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    display: block
}

.work--lockup .slider--item-center {
    position: relative;
    top: 30px;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    display: block
}

.work--lockup .slider--item-center a {
    color: #fff
}

.work--lockup .slider--item-center .slider--item-title {
    margin-top: 25px;
    font-size: 16px
}

.work--lockup .slider--item-center .slider--item-description {
    display: block
}

.work--lockup .slider--item-center .slider--item-image {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px
}

.work--lockup .slider--next,
.work--lockup .slider--prev {
    position: absolute;
    top: 160px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: #282828;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer
}

.work--lockup .slider--next svg,
.work--lockup .slider--prev svg {
    width: 20px;
    fill: #fff
}

.work--lockup .slider--next {
    right: 0
}

.work--lockup .slider--prev {
    left: 0
}

@media (max-width: 900px) {
    .work--lockup .slider--item-image {
        width: 120px;
        height: 120px
    }

    .work--lockup .slider--item-center .slider--item-image {
        width: 240px;
        height: 240px
    }

    .work--lockup .slider--next,
    .work--lockup .slider--prev {
        top: 130px
    }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .work--lockup .slider {
        width: 75%
    }

    .work--lockup .slider--item-image {
        width: 90px;
        height: 90px
    }

    .work--lockup .slider--item-center .slider--item-image {
        width: 190px;
        height: 190px
    }

    .work--lockup .slider--next,
    .work--lockup .slider--prev {
        top: 105px
    }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .work--lockup .slider {
        width: auto
    }

    .work--lockup .slider--item-left,
    .work--lockup .slider--item-right {
        display: none
    }
}
```

JS:

```js
  function workSlider() {

    $('.slider--prev, .slider--next').click(function() {

      var $this = $(this),
          curLeft = $('.slider').find('.slider--item-left'),
          curLeftPos = $('.slider').children().index(curLeft),
          curCenter = $('.slider').find('.slider--item-center'),
          curCenterPos = $('.slider').children().index(curCenter),
          curRight = $('.slider').find('.slider--item-right'),
          curRightPos = $('.slider').children().index(curRight),
          totalWorks = $('.slider').children().length,
          $left = $('.slider--item-left'),
          $center = $('.slider--item-center'),
          $right = $('.slider--item-right'),
          $item = $('.slider--item');

      $('.slider').animate({ opacity : 0 }, 400);

      setTimeout(function(){

      if ($this.hasClass('slider--next')) {
        if (curLeftPos < totalWorks - 1 && curCenterPos < totalWorks - 1 && curRightPos < totalWorks - 1) {
          $left.removeClass('slider--item-left').next().addClass('slider--item-left');
          $center.removeClass('slider--item-center').next().addClass('slider--item-center');
          $right.removeClass('slider--item-right').next().addClass('slider--item-right');
        }
        else {
          if (curLeftPos === totalWorks - 1) {
            $item.removeClass('slider--item-left').first().addClass('slider--item-left');
            $center.removeClass('slider--item-center').next().addClass('slider--item-center');
            $right.removeClass('slider--item-right').next().addClass('slider--item-right');
          }
          else if (curCenterPos === totalWorks - 1) {
            $left.removeClass('slider--item-left').next().addClass('slider--item-left');
            $item.removeClass('slider--item-center').first().addClass('slider--item-center');
            $right.removeClass('slider--item-right').next().addClass('slider--item-right');
          }
          else {
            $left.removeClass('slider--item-left').next().addClass('slider--item-left');
            $center.removeClass('slider--item-center').next().addClass('slider--item-center');
            $item.removeClass('slider--item-right').first().addClass('slider--item-right');
          }
        }
      }
      else {
        if (curLeftPos !== 0 && curCenterPos !== 0 && curRightPos !== 0) {
          $left.removeClass('slider--item-left').prev().addClass('slider--item-left');
          $center.removeClass('slider--item-center').prev().addClass('slider--item-center');
          $right.removeClass('slider--item-right').prev().addClass('slider--item-right');
        }
        else {
          if (curLeftPos === 0) {
            $item.removeClass('slider--item-left').last().addClass('slider--item-left');
            $center.removeClass('slider--item-center').prev().addClass('slider--item-center');
            $right.removeClass('slider--item-right').prev().addClass('slider--item-right');
          }
          else if (curCenterPos === 0) {
            $left.removeClass('slider--item-left').prev().addClass('slider--item-left');
            $item.removeClass('slider--item-center').last().addClass('slider--item-center');
            $right.removeClass('slider--item-right').prev().addClass('slider--item-right');
          }
          else {
            $left.removeClass('slider--item-left').prev().addClass('slider--item-left');
            $center.removeClass('slider--item-center').prev().addClass('slider--item-center');
            $item.removeClass('slider--item-right').last().addClass('slider--item-right');
          }
        }
      }

    }, 400);

    $('.slider').animate({ opacity : 1 }, 400);

    });

  }
```

I haven't try anything cause I have no clue why this happens.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Because the `<path>` of `slider--next` is messed up with some garbage code. A copy/paste gone wrong, maybe?

Comment: If you don't know where to start: did you write this code? Or even, could you have written this code? Because if you didn't, then not knowing where to even start looking for errors is going to be a constant uphill battle.

Comment: I did write the Code and I program for 8 years already but I have never seen something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your path here was wrong here. `<div class="slider--next">`

Here is the modified working HTML code.

```
    <li class="l-section section">
        <div class="work">
            <h2>Contact me</h2>
            <div class="work--lockup">
                <ul class="slider">
                    <li class="slider--item slider--item-left">
                        <a href="mailto:mail">
                            <div class="slider--item-image">
                                <img src="assets/img/work-victory.jpg" alt="E-Mail" />
                            </div>
                            <p class="slider--item-title">E-Mail</p>
                            <p class="slider--item-description">
                                Send me an E-Mail and I would love to help you.
                            </p>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="slider--item slider--item-center">
                        <a href="#0">
                            <div class="slider--item-image">
                                <img src="assets/img/work-metiew-smith.jpg" alt="Fiverr" />
                            </div>
                            <p class="slider--item-title">Fiverr</p>
                            <p class="slider--item-description">
                                Book me directly on Fiverr and get you Website done in a few
                                days.
                            </p>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="slider--item slider--item-right">
                        <a href="#0">
                            <div class="slider--item-image">
                                <img src="assets/img/work-alex-nowak.jpg" alt="Shop" />
                            </div>
                            <p class="slider--item-title">Shop</p>
                            <p class="slider--item-description">
                                Check out my premium Templates and exclusive services.
                            </p>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="slider--prev">
                    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 150 118"
                        style="enable-background: new 0 0 150 118" xml:space="preserve">
                        <g transform="translate(0.000000,118.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)">
                            <path d="M561,1169C525,1155,10,640,3,612c-3-13,1-36,8-52c8-15,134-145,281-289C527,41,562,10,590,10c22,0,41,9,61,29
                                c55,55,49,64-163,278L296,510h575c564,0,576,0,597,20c46,43,37,109-18,137c-19,10-159,13-590,13l-565,1l182,180
                                c101,99,187,188,193,199c16,30,12,57-12,84C631,1174,595,1183,561,1169z" />
                        </g>
                    </svg>
                </div>
                <div class="slider--next">
                    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 150 118"
                        style="enable-background: new 0 0 150 118" xml:space="preserve">
                        <g transform="translate(0.000000,118.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)">
                            <path d="M870,1167c-34-17-55-57-46-90c3-15,81-100,194-211l187-185l-565-1c-431,0-571-3-590-13c-55-28-64-94-18-137c21-20,
                            33-20,597-20h575l-192-193C800,103,794,94,849,39c20-20,39-29,61-29c28,0,63,30,298,262c147,144,272,271,279,282c30,51,23,
                            60-219,304C947,1180,926,1196,870,1167z" />
                        </g>
                    </svg>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</div>
```